# Left Merge Creating New Rows

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, left-join, jupyter

I am trying to build a table of matched orders. I have two source tables, one that has all orders and one that has all matches. The order table has the order ID, the side (buy or sell), and the match status (among other things). The Match table has columns called Bid ID and Ask ID which tie to the order id that submitted the bid or ask (these are the same column in Order). The goal is to have all of the data from the match table added to matched orders in the Order table so I end up with a table that has all orders (regardless of match status) and the match info if they matched.

My Process is splitting the Order table into Matched and Unmatched, and then again splitting Matched into Buy and Sell:

```
split1 = Orders.groupby(Orders.status)
OrdersUM = split1.get_group("CLOSED")
OrdersM = split1.get_group("MATCHED")

split2 = OrdersM.groupby(Orders.side)
OrdersBid = split2.get_group("BUY")
OrdersAsk = split2.get_group("SELL")
```

I then Merge the Match data to the Order data first for Buy then for Sell

```
MOrdersAsk = pd.merge(
    OrdersAsk,
    Match,
    how="left",
    left_on='key',
    right_on='ask_id',
    suffixes=("_O", "_M"),
)

MOrdersBid = OrdersBid.merge(
    Match,
    how="left",
    left_on='key',
    right_on='bid_id',
    suffixes=("_O", "_M"),
)
```

However, after merging I end up with a Buy or Sell table that had more rows than it did before the merge. I would have thought that this was impossible since it is a left merge but there we are.

If it is relevant, each Sell order can be matched with multiple Buy orders and vice versa. The Buy and Sell represent the total order but there can be multiple counterparties, each resulting in a unique Match (ie a match only has 1 buy and 1 sell ID). I then use Append to bring the tables back to a single table.

This is on Python 3.8.5, Pandas 1.1.3, Numpy 1.19.2

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame might be containing duplicate values, that is one reason for left merge to create more rows. You can drop clear the duplicate values using **drop_duplicates()** method and try.